# How to run curl command with parameter in a loop from bash script?

Tags: bash, loops, curl, scripting

I have a curl command I would like to execute in a for loop.
For example I wanted to loop 1-100 times and when curl command runs it uses iterator variable value in the curl command itself.
something like

```
#!/bin/bash
  for i in {1..10}
 do
    curl -s -k 'GET' -H 'header info' -b 'stuff' 'http://example.com/id=$i'        
 done
 --notice here I want var i to be changing with every curl.
```

Anything helps
Thanks.

Comment: Variables are not expanded inside single quotes. Use double quotes instead.

Answer (score 53):

Try this:

```
set -B                  # enable brace expansion
for i in {1..10}; do
  curl -s -k 'GET' -H 'header info' -b 'stuff' 'http://example.com/id='$i
done
```

See: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: looking good. Thank you sir.

Comment: also found out that i cannot use 1..10 format it gotto be listed out like {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} annoying

Comment: Why can't you use `1..10`? What version of `bash` are you using?

Comment: Try `for i in $(seq 1 10); do`

Comment: bash 4.3.30 version.

Comment: Post output of: `for i in {1..10}; do echo -n "$i "; done`

Comment: I am getting {1..10} as the output

Comment: `curl -s -k 'GET' -H 'header info' -b 'stuff' 'http://example.com/id=[1-10]'`
 **curl** can process sequences, no need to iterate manually,

Comment: @TeddKatayama curl can send multiple request but that is sequential. The above script can be in parallel if we just add "&" at the curl command

Comment: `curl -s -Z 'GET' -H 'header info' -b 'stuff' 'http://example.com/id=[1-10]'`
@roneo Curl also supports parallel requests via `–parallel / -Z` flag.